# Use your Atlas to figure out where you are

Tags: word, wordplay, knowledge

You will need your Mind for this one.

For my Intro I will state that you lost your way at Dusk and are now lost in a not Far Away land. Under a Half Moon, you must Take Care to figure out where you are Without A Sound. You only have two clues:

Here does not rhyme with mouse. And though they may be Native, they only stay for the Warmth.

Here, when there is a Flatline, a Flashlight may be needed to combat the Blackout.

This Puzzle may be hard, but When You See It, You'll Know. By now, the pieces should already be Falling Into Place.

Where are you?

And On Your Way Out, thanks for stopping by.

Comment: something something capital letters

Comment: If I'm correct with my answer, this seems extraordinarily narrowly focused.  You either know that exact [domain knowledge] or you don't.

Comment: @MarkPeters I always intended for it to be Googled, I didn't expect anyone to know every single bit of the puzzle. They still needed to figure out what they were looking for though. Good job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> Home

Here does not rhyme with mouse

> House rhymes with mouse, which was a hint that it was "home".

For the rest of the capitalized clues

> Google tells me that they are all names of songs for some band named *[Home](https://soundcloud.com/home-2001/tracks)* which I had never heard of.  This basically seems like an advertisement for that band.

Comment: @PatrickCook: I think the wordplay was good!  I don't mean to discourage you from contributing, it's just a lot of people invest time into solving riddles like this on the assumption that it can be worked out logically, only to find they really never had a hope without knowing about that subject (I think most would consider Googling cheating and would only do so to check their answer).  But I think the riddle shows a lot of promise, and if maybe it were commonly known song titles from a variety of artists (or one extremely well known artist) it would work really well!